# How many notification an app can send to oreo client?

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, push-notification

My app is targeting `Api Level 27` , when i send notification, it successfully receive notification for first time, either app is closed or open.

But after that, it fails to display notificaiton

I want to know if there is any time interval defined in oreo.

I am using latest firebase sdk.

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'

**Firebase Implementation.**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
    Map data = remoteMessage.getData();
    Log.d("MSG", "onMessageReceived: "+data);

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    Set<String> keys = remoteMessage.getData().keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {
        try {
            jsonObject.put(key, remoteMessage.getData().get(key));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    try {
        SharedPreferences appPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(SHARD_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String notifcation_settings = appPrefs.getString(NOTIFICATION_ENABLED, "");

        message= jsonObject.getString("message");

        if(!jsonObject.isNull("urlToOpen")){
            urlToOpen= jsonObject.getString("urlToOpen");
        }

        sendNotification(message, urlToOpen);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}





private void sendNotification(final String msg, final String urlToOpen) {


    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);


            notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

            intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                        notificationIntent, 0);
            }



            Long getCurrentTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
            int id= Math.abs(getCurrentTime.intValue());

            mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(mContext);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                createNotificationChannel();
                mBuilder.setChannelId(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_channel_general));
            }

            mBuilder
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(intent)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title)).setContentText(msg)
                    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setSound(soundUri)
                    .build();

            notificationManager.notify("packageIid , mBuilder.build());
        }
    });
}



private void createNotificationChannel() {

    String CHANNEL_ID= getResources().getString(R.string.notification_channel_general);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        channel.enableLights(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sending the exact same notification? if so, it will overrite the previous.

Comment: How it fails? To avoid the override put different id in your notification you have int id= Math.abs(getCurrentTime.intValue());, but i don`t see where you use